# `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured` when I try to start the daphne

Tags: python, django, daphne, asgi

I have a django project.
When I start `runserver` - everything is fine. But if I try to start the daphne asynchronous server
(`daphne -p 8001 config.asgi:application`),
I get an error
`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`

Settings in wsgi and asgi are the same
`os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'config.settings')`

Maybe someone came across and can me help?

Here ais full traceback

````
  File "/home/dima/PycharmProjects/TyuMeb/Back_reload/venv/bin/daphne", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(CommandLineInterface.entrypoint())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/dima/PycharmProjects/TyuMeb/Back_reload/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/daphne/cli.py", line 171, in entrypoint
    cls().run(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/dima/PycharmProjects/TyuMeb/Back_reload/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/daphne/cli.py", line 233, in run
    application = import_by_path(args.application)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/dima/PycharmProjects/TyuMeb/Back_reload/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/daphne/utils.py", line 12, in import_by_path
    target = importlib.import_module(module_path)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/dima/PycharmProjects/TyuMeb/Back_reload/config/asgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    from chat import routing
  File "/home/dima/PycharmProjects/TyuMeb/Back_reload/chat/routing.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import consumers
  File "/home/dima/PycharmProjects/TyuMeb/Back_reload/chat/consumers.py", line 9, in <module>
    from chat.models import Conversation, Message
  File "/home/dima/PycharmProjects/TyuMeb/Back_reload/chat/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from main_page.models import UserAccount
  File "/home/dima/PycharmProjects/TyuMeb/Back_reload/main_page/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import (AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin)
  File "/home/dima/PycharmProjects/TyuMeb/Back_reload/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/dima/PycharmProjects/TyuMeb/Back_reload/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 49, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/dima/PycharmProjects/TyuMeb/Back_reload/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 127, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/dima/PycharmProjects/TyuMeb/Back_reload/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 260, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/dima/PycharmProjects/TyuMeb/Back_reload/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 137, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/dima/PycharmProjects/TyuMeb/Back_reload/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/dima/PycharmProjects/TyuMeb/Back_reload/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 72, in _setup
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.```
````